# calling function when function name is json value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json object like

```
var json={
  key1:val1,
  key2:"foo" //as a string
}
```

and i have foo function

```
$scope.foo=function{
  //something
}
```

Now on `ng-click` I want to do something like `ng-click="json.key2()"`

Basically I want to call this `foo` function from it's string name ?

Is it possible ? 
I know it's bad approach, but is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: you can include a function on key2. `key2: function() {…}`

Comment: no that function is a long piece of code , and this entire json object is created in a for loop , so multiple values will point to multiple functions which are kept outside loop

Comment: why is it marked as a duplicate , although that question is one of the approach to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties on an object dynamically by using square-brackets.

For example, in your controller (after declaration of `$scope.foo`):

```
$scope.fn = $scope[json.key2];
```

And in your markup:

```
ng-click="fn()"
```

Comment: ok , i took json also on scope like `$scope.json={....}`then i keep key2 as string only but later down , i make it like $scope.json.key2=$scope.foo